# Default user to 'My Views' in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I want to be able to restrict a Jenkins user to only be able to view certain views and jobs in Jenkins. I set the Overall permission to Read, and the Jobs permission to Read, but this results in the user being able to log in and see the All jobs view. I would like the user to be directed to the My Views page when logged in. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this helps but one thing you can try and do is have naming conventions for your Jenkins jobs then utilize the [Role-based Authorization Strategy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin) - It allows you to set permissions for specific jobs based on certain regex for the name. We use it to restrict access to admin folders, etc...